# Install Intel HD Graphic Drivers on Ubuntu

Tags: intel-graphics, intel

i'm using Ubuntu on Dell Latitude E5420 (4G RAM, i5, HD 3000 ). Some times i feel lag when watching video on Youtube. Can i install HD graphics on newest ver of ubuntu?